# How can I use then() block with RestAssured while using POJO classes?

Tags: rest, rest-assured

While working on RestAssured I came across the concept of Serialization and DeSerialization(POJO Classes) to read and validate the response. I went through some tutorial and was able to create the POJO class based on my response.

However, when I use the POJO class reference in my Tests I am not able to use the then() block for different assertions. Below details might clear things bit more :

TestMethod without POJO :

```
public void listUsers() {
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://reqres.in/";

        Response res = RestAssured.given()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .queryParam("page", 2)
        .when()
        .get("/api/users")
        .then()
        .assertThat().statusCode(200).and()
        .body("page", Matchers.equalTo(2)).and()
        .body("total", Matchers.greaterThanOrEqualTo(1))
        .body("data.email", Matchers.hasItem("george.edwards@reqres.in"))
        .extract().response();
        JsonPath jsonpath = new JsonPath(res.asString());
        System.out.println(jsonpath.get("data[0].email"));

    }
```

Test Method with POJO :

```
public void listUserswithPOJO() {
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://reqres.in/";

        ListUsers res = RestAssured.given()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .queryParam("page", 2)
        .when()
        .get("/api/users").as(ListUsers.class);

        System.out.println(res.getData().get(1).getEmail());

    }
```

Test Class :

```
@Test
    public void listUsersTest() {
        ReqResApi TS1 = new ReqResApi();
        TS1.listUserswithPOJO();
    }
```

I want to keep the assertions of the then block as it is while using POJO classes as well. When I try to do so after as(ListUser.class), it gives the compilation error that then() is undefined for ListUser class.

Is there any way in which I can use both POJO class as well as then() block in my rest assured tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because Return types of these options are different.

```
MainPojo m1 =RestAssured.given().contentType("application/json").queryParam("page", 2).when().get("/api/users")
                .as(MainPojo.class)==> Return Type is ur Class, in this example Main Pojo

        System.out.println(m1.getData().get(0).getFirst_name());



 RestAssured.given().contentType("application/json").queryParam("page", 2).when()
                .get("/api/users").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().body("page", Matchers.equalTo(2)).and()
                .body("total", Matchers.greaterThanOrEqualTo(1))
                .body("data.email", Matchers.hasItem("george.edwards@reqres.in")).extract().response();---> Return Type is Response
```